# navbar slide from side instead of bottom in mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to have the navbar slide from the right side instead of bottom in mobile view. I am using the default bootstarp nav bar and I have customized the color. Similarly if I have sub-menu's will it work the same way (sliding from right to left). Please help.

html code:
    
                                            Menu

```
<div class="navi_links col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
                          <!-- nav bar main links --->
                           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-menu" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                   <!--- link 1 and sub nagigation --->
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">PRODUCTS <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu main-menu-sub">
                                            <li><a href="#">Unit Coolers</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Condensing Units</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Condensers &amp; Fluid Coolers</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Systems</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Others</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Check Inventory</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <!--- link 1 and sub nagigation --->
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu main-menu-sub">
                                            <li><a href="#">Create A Project</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">My Project</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">My Address Book</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <!--- link 1 and sub nagigation --->
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Orders <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu main-menu-sub">
                                            <li><a href="#">Create A Order</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">My Orders</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Shipping Details</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Invoices</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <!--- link 1 and sub nagigation --->
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Tools <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu main-menu-sub">
                                            <li><a href="#">Quick Submittal Drawings</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Quick Box Load Calculator</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Detailed Box Load Calculator</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Quick Energy Calculators</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Parts Lookup</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <!--- link 1 and sub nagigation --->
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Resources <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu main-menu-sub">
                                            <li><a href="#">Literature</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">My Programs</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Contractor Network</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Co-op Advertising</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <!--- link 1 and sub nagigation --->
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Support <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu main-menu-sub">
                                            <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Technical Support</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Warrant</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                  </ul>
                          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for? Check out the link.

https://jsbin.com/zacefalowa/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. For the sub menu is it possible to have it slide from right to left?